# On inversive geometry

Tags: geometry, self-learning, inversive-geometry

I am given the following problem set:

> Observe the circle $K$ with center $0$ and radius $r$ in the complex plane $ \mathbb{C} \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$. Show that the inversion on $K$ is given by the following mapping: $$ i_K : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \\ z \mapsto \frac{r^2}{\bar z}$$

**First thoughts :**
I know that inversions have to fulfill the following properties

- $\forall p \in E\smallsetminus \lbrace z \rbrace: i_K(p)\in \overrightarrow{zp} \      \ $ where $z$ is the origin of circle $K$
- $d(z,p) \cdot d(z, i_k(p)) =r^2$

**Problem :**
Since we just introduced the inversion (with no introduction to hyperbolic geometry) I don't know how to prove the two properties - which I think are necessary to prove the mapping. I am thankful for any kind of help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution :**

We have to fulfill the following two properties that the mapping $$ i_K : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \\ z \mapsto \frac{r^2}{\bar z}$$ states an inversion on a circle $K$

**(a)** $\forall p \in E\smallsetminus \lbrace z \rbrace: i_K(p)\in \overrightarrow{zp} \      \ $ where $z$ is the origin of circle $K$

**(b)** $d(z,p) \cdot d(z, i_k(p)) =r^2$

---

**(a)** $$i_K(p) = \frac {r^2}{\bar p} = \underbrace{\frac{r^2}{\vert p \vert^2}}_{\text{scalar}} \cdot p $$ so this shows us that $i_K$ lies on $\overrightarrow{zp}$

**(b)** \begin{align}d(z,p) \cdot d(z, \frac {r^2}{\bar p}) &= r^2 \\ d(z,p) \cdot d(z, \frac{r^2}{\vert p \vert^2} \cdot p) &= r^2 \\ \vert p\vert \cdot \left \vert \frac{r^2}{\vert p \vert^2} \cdot p\right \vert = r^2 \cdot \left \vert  \frac{\vert p \vert^2}{\vert p \vert^2}  \right \vert &= r^2  \end{align}

and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $z\bar{z} = |z|^2$. It may be helpful to observe that

$$ \bar{z} = \frac{|z|^2}{z} $$

Hyperbolic geometry, incidentally doesn't have anything to do with the inversive plane.

Comment: well how do I then continue ?

Comment: @Mainviel: Well, have you yet plugged in the formula for $i_K$ into the two conditions you're trying to prove? I assumed you had done that already but opted not to post it, and were having trouble with the algebra.

Comment: yes I plugged the formula in and I am struggling with the algebra this is what i got so far $$ \forall p \in E \smallsetminus \lbrace z \rbrace : \frac{r^2}{\bar p} \in \overrightarrow{zp} $$ now for $$ \frac{r^2}{\bar p} = \frac{r^2 p}{\vert p \vert ^2} = r^2 \cdot \frac{1}{\bar p } = \ ? $$

Comment: *Hyperbolic geometry, incidentally doesn't have anything to do with the inversive plane* Well, except for the fact that the half-plane model of Euclidean geometry *does* use Möbius inversions, which is ostensibly the connection the user encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write out what both properties look like with this transformation.

The first one says "$\frac{r^2}{\overline{p}}$ is an $\Bbb R$ scalar multiple of $p$". This is true since $\frac{r^2}{\overline{p}}=p\frac{r^2}{p\overline{p}}$.

The second says $|p||\frac{r^2}{\overline{p}}|=r^2$, which you can easily confirm using the properties of the modulus on complex numbers.